# Removing non-visible text from a post

Tags: discussion, editing

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375337/an-integral-formula-i-cant-find-any-proof) contains a block of text that is not visible when the question is rendered:

> % MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
>   % faaagCart1ev2aaaKnaaaaWenf2ys9wBH5garuavP1wzZbItLDhis9
>   % wBH5garmWu51MyVXgaruWqVvNCPvMCaebbnrfifHhDYfgasaacJ8sr
>   % ps0lbbf9q8WrFfeuY-ribbf9v8qqaqFr0xc9pk0xbba9q8WqFfea0-
>   % yr0RYxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9q8qqQ8frFve9Fve9Ff0dc9Gqpi0d
>   % meaabaqaciGacaGaaeqabaWaaeaaeaaakabbOpW2dS9axHwA0vgape
>   % qaaiaadAgacaGGOaGaey4kaSIaeyOhIuQaaiykaiabgUcaRiaadAga
>   % caGGOaGaeyOeI0IaeyOhIuQaaiykaiabg2da98aadaWfqaqaaiGacY
>   % gacaGGPbGaaiyBaaWcbaGaeqyTduMaeyOKH4QaaGimaiabgUcaRaqa
>   % baGccqaH1oqzdaWdXaqaaiaadsgacqaHepaDaSqaaiabgkHiTiabg6
>   % HiLcqaaiabg6HiLcqdcqGHRiI8aOGaamOzaiaacIcacqaHepaDcaGG
>   % PaGaamyzamaaCaaaleqabaGaeyOeI0IaeqyTduMaaiiFaiabes8a0j
>   % aacYhaaaaaaa!5F91!

It looks like a proprietary file format of something called MathType.

Is it all right to edit it out or should we leave alone?
What if non-visible text is obscene or otherwise falls short of the StackExchange decency standards?

**Update**: it looks like OP edited his/her own question.

Comment: Yes, editing it out is fine.

Comment: Well, nobody can see such weird.. words(?) .But if you have the time to edit them, edit them. Tho I'd say would be better if you edit something else, like titles of questions or retag a question instead of spending time editing something that nobody sees.